# Getting blank page when saving a product in magento

Tags: magento

when i try to save an already existing product page magento gives me a blank page.

the memory_ limit is 256 M (core)

haven't done no recent updations and it was working fine.

Comment: There is not enough information here to provide an answer. Have you checked your logs? Have you tried enabling developer mode?

Comment: I tried  giving ini_set('display_errors', 1);  in index.php but it is not giving any errors. The memory_limit local is set to 768 M (local) and 256 (master)

Comment: It also does not happen with all products.. just a few

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System->Configuration**

Then Enabled the log setting under **Advanced->Developer->Log Setting**

Then save product and then see the `system.log` file into

*/var/www/html/magento/var/log*

**May help you**

For enable error reporting

In Index page change the following:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

to

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Set `$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true`

and uncomment this line `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

In Errors folder rename "local.xml.sample" to local.xml.

hope this help.

> Don't forget to set full access permissions (777) to the following folder: /var/log, since that is the place where those log files are stored.

**UPDATE-1**

to solve the issue please use the following steps:
Clean Magento cache, either using `Flush Cache` at **System -> Configuration -> Cache Magement** in Magento Backend or using **Clean Cache** button at **Store settings** in your Managing panel.

Disable Magento Compiler at the **System -> Tools -> Compilation** screen
One by one, disable recently installed modules at **System -> Configuration > Advanced -> Advanced -> Disable Modules output** and flush Magento cache after each operation.

Comment: My magenta version is 1.6.0. I added  error reporting but its showing me no errors

Answer (score 0):

I open get blank page in Magento in 2 cases bellow:

1. `memory_limit` is not enough
2. `max_execution_time` is not enough

I think you shoud check your php setting for `max_execution_time`

Comment: max_exexution_time is set to 1800